# Drupal 7: Views Link display:Custom URL special character issue

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with more link enabled. And I am trying to link to a node which URL is like eg:

> www.example.com/news?tab-new=3#news-tab_3

but when the link is clicked as an anonymous user the characters in the URL is changed to acii or some other hexa code.

Therefore the link is broken and Page not found is displayed. any suggestion?

Comment: what characters shown?

Comment: - 1. for '?' it is: %3F
 - 2. for '#' it is: %23
 - 3. for '&' it is: %26

Comment: I could not solve this, but instead as an alternative I have created a custom more link using views footer. Which does the same job as 'Link display:Custom URL.